# Как подсчитать число значений?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть текст

```
:hasCategories :Coal , :Energy , :Energy , :Uran , :Uranium , :Oil ;
```

Мне надо только

```
:Coal , :Energy , :Energy , :Uran , :Uranium , :Oil
```

Т.е. хочу в конце получить ответ 6

Каким простым способом мне это сделать?Только регулярка? Как он будет выглядеть?

Comment: двоеточия посчитайте. правда не ясно что делать с первым словом оно не особо отличается от остальных. но если оно есть всегда можно просто вычесть 1 из кол-ва двоеточий

Comment: А повторяющиеся слова, например, Energy - точно по несколько раз считать правильно?

Comment: Помимо этого, в файле достаточно других двоеточий. Повторяющиеся слова пока будем учитывать в подсчете.
Мне надо что-то такое:

Найди :hasCategories
Повторять пока не встретим ";"{
    Повторять пока есть "," {
           count ++;
     }
}

Вывести count.

Но я думаю с регуляркой выдет проще. Только как её написать?

Comment: Совершенно непонятно - какая всё-таки задача стоит? Пример - это хорошо, но задачу в чуть более общем виде тоже нужно описать.

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что пришло в голову:

```php
<?php

$text = ':hasCategories :Coal , :Energy , :Energy , :Uran , :Uranium , :Oil ;';

preg_match_all('~(:\w+)\s*[,;]~', $text, $matches);

echo count($matches[1]); // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = `:fgdjkghfjk :dfadfsafoadfla , :Efafd ;
:hasCategories :Coal , :Energy , :Energy , :Uran , :Uranium , :Oil ;
:fgdjkghfjk :dfadfsafoadfla , :Efafd ;`;

var line = text.match(/:hasCategories ([^;]*);/);

if (line) {
  var data = line[1];
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.match(/:\S+/g));
}
```